# Permission denied when using basic ROS2 CLI

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have just made a fresh installation of ROS2 Galactic following the guide in the documentation. I need to use galactic for the time being because of other dependencies in a project.

If I try to run basic ros2 commands like:

```
ros2 topic list
```

or

```
ros2 node list
```

I get the following error message:

```
Failed opening file /home/martin/.ros/log/python3_87631_1672396098403.log for writing: Permission denied
```

It seems that ros does not have permission to create a new file in the  `.ros/log/` folder.

Have anyone experienced something similar, or know a fix?

Thanks!

**System info**

Linux 5.15.0-56-generic

Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

gcc 9.4.0

ROS_VERSION=2

ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3

ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0

ROS_DISTRO=galactic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410967/permission-denied-when-using-basic-ros2-cli/) by [MasHyke](https://answers.ros.org/users/90158/mashyke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source the ROS2 in the terminal before these commands? Did you use `sudo` with some of the ROS commands during the installation or installing dependencies? Perhaps you did this (from `rosdep -h`):

> `rosdep fix-permissions`   Recursively
> change the permissions of the user's
> ros home directory.   May require
> sudo.  Can be useful to fix
> permissions after calling   `rosdep update` with `sudo` accidentally.

Please check it in your workspace (`sudo rosdep fix-permissions`). Can you check your user groups (`groups`) and show them?

Some related Q&A to check:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/206727/permission-denied/
- https://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-beginner-mistakes-1-missing-execute-permission-on-the-python-file/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/303073/rosserial-permission-denied/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/281477/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-rosrosdepsourcescacheindex/
- https://www.myzhar.com/blog/the-myzharbot-project/software/myzharbot-ros/ros-solving-annoying-permission-denied-gvfs-error-crawling-packages/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/342149/permission-denied-when-importing-tf/

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0